# Wordpress links using page ID stops working if ID is over than the no 2000

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink

Wonder why my Wordpress site that uses page id as link stops working if ID is over than the no 2000. The page id linkage is set up for putting all “pages” created in wp to a single page doc for offline app caching ( ie site can work offline after cached ). The site is still displayed with multiple pages. The pages have random IDs created by WP and although I only have 150 simple text pages the IDs now automatically goes over 2000. If page id links are below the figure 2000, ie page id 1999,1998,1997 links work without problems. But once page id is 2000,2001,2002etc the link went dead and won’t take user to new page. Trying to login my phpadmin but do not know which table to manually amend page id or this is a bad idea? Help please much appreciated.

Comment: Might be some rule in htaccess or functions.php question is generics please be specific so we can help you.

Comment: Shall i paste part of the relevant functions here? Lemme check the htaccess...now

Comment: yes please  add code

Comment: Hi i checked nothing specific in dot htaccess.

Comment: Hi, I pasted codes i think should be relevant in here : 
// Pagination for paged posts, Page 1, Page 2, Page 3, with Next and Previous Links, No plugin
function html5wp_pagination()
{
    global $wp_query;
    $big = 999999999;
    echo paginate_links(array(
        'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link($big)),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
    ));
}

Comment: Yes please added code here

Comment: // Passed classes.
        $classes = empty($item->classes) ? array() : (array)$item->classes;
        $class_names = esc_attr(implode(' ', apply_filters('nav_menu_css_class', array_filter($classes), $item)));
        $itemLink = "#page_" . get_post_meta($item->ID, '_menu_item_object_id', true);
        if (strstr($class_names, 'menu-item-has-children')) {
            $class_names = 'parent';
            $itemLink = "javascript:;";
        }

Comment: may I have website url?

Comment: Hi, can you move discussion to chat as i newly joined so i couldnt do so.

Comment: No actually its appear automatically

Comment: it says i only have 1 reputation and cannot move discussion to chat...

Comment: I can not do the same please continue discussion here

Comment: Oh. cus my site has a password it is not publicly available :<

Comment: Yes this is case that's reason I have asked htaccess

Comment: Ok let me add in answer

Comment: Hi sorry i don't know what you mean. i had open the dot htaccess file but appears nothing in particular related to the prbl i ran into. pls advice the right direction...

Comment: Generally plugins are add rule in htaccess when you want to redirect or restrict page related thigs. Its easiest way to do as well as no need to modify a php file.

Comment: Oh i see. no the previous programmers do many stuff hand coded in the functions :< maybe internet said its the loop thats not right.

Comment: ok its solved right?

Comment: Not solved:< The page ID linking to 1998,1999 is all ok but once it gets to over the figure of 2000, the links won't go. Do u think we can amend the pageID to some pages that iv now deleted(for eg i deleted some pages with IDs of 950,951..952...? and amend those over 2000 in my phpadmin into IDs thats lower than 2000 (to 950,951,,952)?

Comment: just do one things

Comment: take backup of database and switch theme to default database

Comment: Ok i thought so lemme try!!

Comment: Hi. it is the theme, the functions being re-written hard coded with many bits. I switch theme and switch server and decided something in the functions is causing this. Still don't know how to fix...

Answer (score 0):

Please perfrom following step :

- Check a plugin if you are using for permalink\
- Check htaccess for page rule
- switch to default theme if function.php have conditional code
- Check you page should not be private or password protected.

Comment: Hi, i found out when i switch server same issues there and wen switch back to default wp theme the links works - so something in the functions is causing the issues :< maybe i will try hard debug but probably would break the offline caching :<